# What am I missing? SQL Conversion Failure

Tags: sql, sql-server, integer, varchar

I'm trying to add `stf.PrimarySchoolID` (an integer) into this existing query. I have a bat file that will use this SQL statement to export a CSV. However, when I open the exported CSV I receive this error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Server [SERVER NAME], Line 13
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',"' to data type int.
```

*Note: `stf.StaffNumber` is not an integer, it is alpha-numeric.*

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT '"'+
    stf.StaffNumber +'","'+
    stf.LastName +'","'+
    stf.FirstName +'","' +
    COALESCE(u.username, '')+'","'+
    COALESCE(sfc.[NAME],'') +'",'+
    stf.PrimarySchoolID
FROM dbo.UDF_GetCurrentAcademicSessions() cur
    JOIN dbo.Course c ON c.AcadSessionID = cur.AcadSessionId            
    JOIN dbo.Staff stf ON stf.StaffID = c.PrimaryTeacherID
    JOIN dbo.StaffClassification sfc ON sfc.StaffClassificationID = stf.PrimaryClassificationID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[User] u ON u.UserID = stf.UserID
```

Do you spot a mistake on my part? I'm not very experienced with SQL statements, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting `stf.StaffNumber` to a VARCHAR before appending to it:

```
CAST(stf.StaffNumber AS VARCHAR)
```

The same applies for any numeric values that you're appending a string to.

**EDIT**

I believe this should cover everything:

```
SELECT '"'+    
CAST(stf.StaffNumber AS VARCHAR) +'",'+    
CAST(stf.PrimarySchoolID AS VARCHAR) +',"'+    
stf.LastName +'","'+    
stf.FirstName +'","' +    
ISNULL(u.username, '')+'","'+    
ISNULL(sfc.[NAME],'') +'",'+    
CAST(stf.PrimarySchoolID AS VARCHAR)
```

On a side note, you should use `ISNULL` in cases where there's only one condition. `COALESCE` will work fine, but it's wired for multiple conditions, i.e. `COALESCE(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)`

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you and thanks for the info on COALESCE. Everyone's answer was correct, however, I chose yours because you caught & included the fix for another error of *my own doing*: repeating the `stf.PrimarySchoolID` :P

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line of the `SELECT` to:

`CAST(stf.PrimarySchoolID as varchar)`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to CAST `stf.PrimarySchoolID` to a character type.

```
...
CAST(stf.PrimarySchoolID AS VARCHAR(20)) -- You can fix length as needed
...
```

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you. And, thanks for including the varchar length. Looked info up about it & I learned about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `stf.PrimarySchoolID` to a character type (say, varchar) before using it in a concatenation:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT '"'+
    stf.StaffNumber +'",'+
    convert(varchar, stf.PrimarySchoolID) +',"'+
    stf.LastName +'","'+
    stf.FirstName +'","' +
    COALESCE(u.username, '')+'","'+
    COALESCE(sfc.[NAME],'') +'",'+
    stf.PrimarySchoolID
FROM dbo.UDF_GetCurrentAcademicSessions() cur
    JOIN dbo.Course c ON c.AcadSessionID = cur.AcadSessionId            
    JOIN dbo.Staff stf ON stf.StaffID = c.PrimaryTeacherID
    JOIN dbo.StaffClassification sfc ON sfc.StaffClassificationID = stf.PrimaryClassificationID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[User] u ON u.UserID = stf.UserID
```

You can do type cast either using [SQL Server's `CONVERT` or SQL ANSI's `CAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Since stf.PrimarySchoolID is an int and you are trying to concatenate it to a varchar() field, you are getting this error. Try the foll:

```
SELECT '"'+
    stf.StaffNumber +'",'+
    cast(stf.PrimarySchoolID as varchar(10)) +',"'+
    stf.LastName +'","'+
    stf.FirstName +'","' +
    COALESCE(u.username, '')+'","'+
    COALESCE(sfc.[NAME],'') +'",'+
    stf.PrimarySchoolID
```

Answer (score -1):

Joining tables columns may not be matching or joining on given columns. Double check on what columns, logic are given to join.